# is it possible to have optional parameters in templates in web.py

Tags: python, web.py

Is it possible to have optional parameters in templates in web.py. Suppose you want to pass error messages only if an error has occured, how would you go about doing it ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Templetor, the web.py template system [is just Python code embedded in HTML files](http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/templetor) (with a couple limitations), so yes, you can pass optional parameters using [*args and **kwargs](http://agiliq.com/blog/2012/06/understanding-args-and-kwargs/), for example:

```
$def with(**kwargs)
$if kwargs['error']:
    <p class=error>$kwargs['error']</p>
```